# Java - bundle JFrame icon in .jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jframe, embedded-resource

I am trying to set an icon for a JFrame. It works perfectly when I run it from inside Eclipse, but when I export the program as a runnable .jar file, the default coffee cup icon is present instead.

Code:

```
frame.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("res/icon.png"));
```

Project structure:

[image: Project]

I have tried exporting with both "Extract required libraries into generated JAR" and "Package required libraries into generated JAR". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `res` is apparently a source folder, so you should just have `"/icon.png"`. In any case, open up your JAR, and see where it is.

Comment: Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Comment: @Tunaki, that still didn't work, unfortunatly. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Unzip your JAR. Is the file in there at least?

Comment: @Tunaki Yes, it's in the root folder

Comment: Then refer to the linked question to load the image properly from the classpath. You can't use the `getImage(String)` method, since that works on files, not resources on the classpath.